# What is the hyperbolic angle as a function of $f(t)$ and, in general, two points?

Tags: special-relativity

What is the hyperbolic angle as a function of $f(t)$ and, in general, two points $(f(t),t)$ and $(f(t+a)$,$t+a)$?

Is the following a valid way to define hyperbolic angle using $f(t)$ and $t$?

Assumptions:

$t>f(t)$,

$\cosh \phi = \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-f(t)^2}} = \frac{e^\phi + e^{-\phi}}{2}$,

$\sinh \phi = \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t^2-f(t)^2}} = \frac{e^\phi - e^{-\phi}}{2}$,

where $\phi$ is the hyperbolic angle.

Then,

$$\cosh\phi + \sinh\phi =e^\phi = \frac{t+f(t)}{\sqrt{t^2-f(t)^2}}.$$

Taking the $\ln$ of both sides gives

$$\phi(t) = \ln\frac{t+f(t)}{\sqrt{t^2-f(t)^2}}.$$
$$\phi(t) = \ln\sqrt{\frac{t+f(t)}{t-f(t)}}.$$

If the result above isn't valid, then what would the hyperbolic angle as a function of $f(t)$ be?

Note: The assumptions are not negative, I've used "-" as a bullet point.

Comment: Also please don't use mathematical symbols at the start of equations as bullet points...

Comment: When you compose your question or answer, there is a "bulleted list" button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where this question came from or where this question is going.

But by division, one has $$\tanh\phi=\frac{\sinh\phi}{\cosh\phi}=\frac{f}{t}.$$

So, $$\phi={\rm arctanh}\left(\displaystyle \frac{f}{t}\right).$$

---

UPDATE:

So, if the curve $(f(t),t)$ describes a [timelike] straight line through the origin event O, then
$$f(t)=v t,$$ where $v$ is a constant that could be described as a "slope" (for a spacetime geometry, this would be the "velocity").

Due to the nature of the "rotations" implied by Einstein's postulates (the boosts of the Lorentz group),
the "circle" that is invariant under the rotations (boosts) can be described by
$(\sinh\phi,\cosh\phi)$, where $\phi$ is an additive parameter which could be associated with the arc-length along the "unit circle" (a unit hyperbola for special relativity).

So, this "slope" $v$ is equal to $\tanh\phi$.

[If we were dealing with Euclidean geometry,
there would be instead a circle describable by $(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$.
Then, the slope $v$ of the straight line would equal to $\tan\theta$.]

To derive the "angle measure", 
use the definition "circular arc-length divided by the radius of the circle",
using the metric of your geometry.

In special relativity (with metric $ds^2=dt^2-dx^2$ and "circle" [the future hyperbola, with spacelike tangents] $R^2=t^2-x^2$),
the angle (called the rapidity) is the spacelike-arc length divided by the timelike radial length.
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi
&=&\frac{1}{R}\int dL\\
&=& \frac{1}{R}\int \sqrt{dx^2-dt^2}\\
&=& \frac{1}{R}\int {dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)^2}}\\
&=& \frac{1}{R}\int {dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)^2}}\\
&=& \frac{1}{R}\int {dx}\frac{\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}{t}\\
&=& \frac{1}{R}\int {dx}\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2+x^2}}\\
&=& \int {dx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2+x^2}}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
where we have used that the slope of the tangent line to the "circle" (the hyperbola)
$\displaystyle\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{x}{t}$.
This integrates to ${\rm arcsinh}(x/R)+C$.
This is how the hyperbolic function arises from this approach.

Comment: very fair. The reason why I'm asking this is because of something I noticed about the derivation of a derivative; it's based on the definition of the slope between two points. I'm curious what the result would be if the definition of a slope within the derivation of a derivative was changed to the definition of a hyperbolic angle. First, I need to be able to define the hyperbolic angle between two points without using hyperbolic functions like archtanh

Comment: @ajay Angles are defined between rays, which can be associated with two point-events on a hyperbola. Angles can defined in terms of the Minkowski arc-length on the unit hyperbola and in terms of the area of the hyperbolic sector cut by those rays.

Comment: thank for the the time you put into this. I’ve made a copy and will go through, but I’ve been asked to move this to mathematics side and may have to delete. My apologies for this

Comment: @ajay There's no need to delete your question. And you definitely should *not* try to delete a question when it's received a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks, I’m new to this process and didn’t know how it worked.